# Error using APNS in php

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

trying to use APNS-PHP for making push notifications.. keep getting these errors

```
Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:53:40 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: 
INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... 
Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:54:22 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': Connection timed out (110)
 Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:54:22 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: INFO: Retry to connect (1/3)... 
Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:54:23 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... 
Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:55:06 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': Connection timed out (110)
 Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:55:06 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: INFO: Retry to connect (2/3)... Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:55:07 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
 Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:55:49 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': Connection timed out (110) Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:55:49 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: INFO: Retry to connect (3/3)... 
Tue, 06 Mar 2012 08:55:50 -0700 ApnsPHP[12396]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
```

have anyone got something like this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe port 2195 is blocked or certificate is the problem.

Comment: checked, they are not blocked and the certificates are ok